# Using sed, delete from specific line until first match(not included)

Tags: sed

I have some data looks like

```
1:Alice 2313
2:Desctop 456
3:Cook 111
4:.filename 50
...
...
100:Good 3
Dir num:10
File num:90
...
...
```

I want to delete all lines from specific line(ex. line 3) until the line "Dir num:" show up.
The idea output should be(according above example):

```
1:Alice 2313
2:Desctop 456
Dir num:10
File num:90
...
...
```

I have google several solutions like`sed -i '/somestring/,$!d' file`.
But these solutions are not suitable because of the specific line where deletion satarting.

How can I do this in 1 command without any tmp file?
Forgive my poor English, I'm not native English speaker.

Comment: `sed -i` uses a tmp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the address range from the specified line number (`3`) to the line matching the pattern (`/Dir num/`). However, it's not quite as simple as

```
sed '3,/Dir num/ d' file
```

because that will delete the "Dir num" line. Try this instead:

```
sed '3,/Dir num/ {/Dir num/! d}' file
```

That will, for the lines in the range, check that the line does **not** match the pattern: is the pattern is *not matched*, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `range: /pattern1/,/pattern2/` option of `sed`

```
$ sed -e '/2:Desctop 456/,/Dir num:10/{//!d}' inputFile
1:Alice 2313
2:Desctop 456
Dir num:10
File num:90
...
...
```